# Is it possible to use JDK 21 in an Azure Pipeline Gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, azure-pipelines

My Azure pipeline contains the following task

```yaml
  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: 'Run checks and tests'
    inputs:
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
      tasks: 'check jacocoTestCoverageVerification jacocoTestReport'
```

I would like to upgrade to JDK v21, but if I replace 1.17 with 1.21 I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to find the specified JDK version. Please ensure the specified JDK version is installed on the agent and the environment variable 'JAVA_HOME_21_X64' exists and is set to the location of a corresponding JDK or use the Java Tool Installer task to install the desired JDK.

I also tried using using `Gradle@3` with `jdkVersionOption: '1.21'`, but it fails with the same error message

Comment: Have you included/updated the gradle wrapper in your project for it to use? Also keep in mind that gradle doesn't have full support for java 21 yet https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: @AnthonyCathers I don't think I need to upgrade the Gradle Wrapper, because the Gradle version hasn't changed

Comment: If you're upgrading your java version to a latest version, you should almost always be updating your gradle wrapper to a version that supports that java version. But I think the issue here is that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/fundamentals/java-support-on-azure 21 is just not provided by Azure out of the box. You would probably need to provide a custom container to run this in until support is provided

Comment: @AnthonyCathers I'm already using the latest version of Gradle (8.4), so there's no version I could upgrade to

Comment: Gradle only supports certain versions which is why I posted the compatibility matrix. You never said what version of gradle you were on until this last comment. It was a general comment, not meant to be taken literally. The answer to your original question is also within my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Java21 in Azure Pipeline.

The root cause of the issue is that the Java 21 is not pre-installed in Pipeline agent.

> Is it possible to use JDK 21 in an Azure Pipeline Gradle task?

The answer is YES. We can add steps to install the Java 21 before Gradle build.

Refer to the following YAML sample:

**Windows Agent:**

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $source = "https://download.oracle.com/java/21/latest/jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.zip"
   $destination = "$(build.sourcesdirectory)\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.zip"
   $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
   $cookie = "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
   $client.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie) 
   $client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use Java 21'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 21
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
    jdkFile: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.zip'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk21'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.21'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'build'
```

**Linux Agent:**

```
steps:
- bash: 'wget --no-check-certificate -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" https://download.oracle.com/java/21/latest/jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz '
  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use Java 21'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 21
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
    jdkFile: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk21'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.21'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'build'
```

The script will download the Java 21  [Java Official site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk21-linux). And the Pipeline task: [Java Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/java-tool-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines) to configure the agent environemnt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder if this could be further simplified by using https://sdkman.io/ to install the JDK instead?

Comment: Yes. This method also can work i think. But the tool sdkman is also not pre-installed in MS hosted agent, you need to install the tool first.  All in all, you need to complete the installation of Java 21 before running the GradleTask . Then the issue will be resolved

Comment: It worked like a charm. For reference here is the equivalent `wget` command to download the Eclipse Temurin (OpenJDK) distro `wget https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/21/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse -O jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Comment: Does anyone know if the provided default java version in azure devops runner is now jdk 21? The docs still talk about jdk 17